# DB2 indoubt transactions can be resolved by instance restart?

Tags: db2

I have read the KC saying how to manually resolve indoubt xn using list indoubt transaction with prompting command but want understand

1. if these indoubt transaction are at instance level?
2. Can instance restart also solve these indoubt transaction?

Answer (score 0):

In-doubt transactions can only happen in a distributed database scenario, i.e., with 2 or more databases involved in a single distributed ("global") transaction. A typical reason for in-doubt transaction is lost network communication, the local transaction does not know whether the global/distributed transaction committed successfully.

1) The in-doubt transactions are per database and need to be resolved at that level.
2) The instance restart does not change the transaction state.

The [X/Open distributed transaction processing protocol for DB2](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.2pc.doc/doc/c0004558.html) in the Knowledge Center.